# Spring XD - JDBC Sink configuration | columns: option named 'columns' is not supported

Tags: jdbc, spring-xd, sink

I am using spring-xd-1.0.0.M6.

I try to configure mysql DB as a sink for the Spring-xd

I follow -http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.in/2014/01/springxd-filetail-input-ingestion-jdbc.html

I put my jdbc.properties file - in the

1) `spring-xd-1.0.0.M6/xd/modules/sink/jdbc/config`  location

2) I put mysql connector jar in the

```
spring-xd-1.0.0.M6/xd/lib
```

I create a file - input.txt and put it in the folder - `/<some path>/temp/input.txt`

The file contains

```
{"id":"1","name":"pas"}
{"id":"2","name":"lucia"}
{"id":"3","name":"lucas"}
{"id":"4","name":"siena"}
```

jdbc file contains following informations.

```
driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring_xd
username=root
password=root
```

Now in the XD shell I execute following

```
stream create --name filetest --definition "tail --name='/<some path>/temp/input.txt' |  jdbc --columns='id,name'" --deploy
```

My my-sql DB table name is - file_test  and it has 2 columns id and name - same as mentioned in the `Example Link`

But I get

```
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module jdbc of type sink:
    columns: option named 'columns' is not supported
```

If I specify the tableName param,  also I get ..

```
tableName: option named 'tableName' is not supported
```

I also refer - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/pull/621

But clue less .... with latest Spring-xd build

Comment: I'd suggest using XD 1.0.0.M4, just like that blog post. These are milestone versions and things change pretty quickly from one release to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you put your .properties file is not meant to configure the module, but declare which options are available. By putting it there, you've basically declared that the `jdbc` module has no options (as you're in fact not using the correct syntax).

Instead, you need to put the .properties file you mention elsewhere. Note that the exact location being picked up has changed between releases. I suggest using the latest release (M7 at the time of writing). Then, the correct location is

```
${xd.home}/config/modules/sink/jdbc/jdbc.properties
```

and not

```
${xd.home}/modules/sink/jdbc/config/jdbc.properties
```

Note that the XD release currently does provide such a file out of the box, whose contents looks like:

```
url = ${spring.datasource.url}
driverClassName = ${spring.datasource.driverClassName}
username = ${spring.datasource.username}
password = ${spring.datasource.password}
```

This is to have the jdbc module use the values defined in `server.yml` by default